# Are SpaceX subject to "Common Carrier" provisions from the FAA, NASA or others?

Tags: law, commercial

[For instance](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34508/20636), could SpaceX refuse to carry OneWeb satellites because it is a competitor to StarLink.

Obviously SpaceX shouild be able refuse payloads as incompatible with their vehicle.

The obvious sources of the imposition of [common carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_carrier) conditions would be the regulator, the FAA, and NASA who provide the launch sites and support facilities.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much a duplicate of uhoh's question, hopefully worded in a more answerable way, and without potentially offensive tangents.

Comment: deliberate duplicate of the 4 hour old question [If OneWeb asked SpaceX to launch their satellites would SpaceX be able to say no?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34508/12102) is probably not the best way to use Stack Exchange. Better behavior includes leaving helpful comments, offering to make a helpful edit (which can be rolled back) or even in some cases to go ahead and make a helpful edit. It sounds like you have some thoughts on the topic, why not leave an answer there instead?

Comment: I think this is the interesting question at it's core, but short of editing it into this form I don't think it is salvagable, and that would be too severe an edit for me to consider making to someone else's question.

Comment: You are trying to circumvent Stack Exchange's voting process and unilaterally have your own way by insta-duping my question. A single user never gets to decide what is "salvageable" unless its the OP themselves. SE rules apply to everyone equally.

Comment: exactly @uhoh. the users will vote as appropriate. No Further Comment